# `Any` and `Duration` types undefined

Tags: grpc, asp.net-core-2.1, protocol-buffers

I am on .Net Core 3.0 and tried to use the following Protobuf types but they are undefined:

(1) `Any` => Any .Net Core framework types

(2) `Duration` => TimeSpan

Answer (score 0):

```
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";
import "google/protobuf/duration.proto";
```

Comment: Although this may be a correct answer. Two lines of code isn't very useful without an explanation of what and how it solves the original question. Please provide details to your answer.